# Why my python script sometimes stopping and waiting for keypress?

Tags: python-3.x

I noticed something on my script. Sometimes it stops and when I press any keys on my keyboard it resumes. I didnt put any keypress command on my script. It's running on a windows vps.

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: It would be better If you could post a snippet of your code where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. When i clicked on the terminal the script pauses. To fix this go to terminal properties then uncheck the quick edit.